# How to query both samaaccountname and userprincipalname symfonyLdap

Tags: symfony, ldap

I have a Symfony login form authenticating against an Ldap server. I can successfully query and authenticate a user using either samaccountname or userprincipalname and the uid key in my config settings. I want to be able to allow the user to enter either their username or their username@domain.com

I have tried a preg_replace on the username in the loadUserbyUsername() method in the LdapUserProviderClass (I know is not ideal). That takes a username such as username@domain.com and passes on username. I was able to verify that the correct user was returned from the Ldap server but I'm still returned to the login form with 'Invalid Credentials'. I believe the reason why this happens in the AuthenticationUtils class request is processed and the username in the request is still username@domain.com and that does not match the username in the user object coming from the Ldap authentication which is username. If anyone has advice on how to accomplish allowing both username@domain.com and username being authenticated against Ldap I would greatly appreciate it.

SecurityController.php

```
 public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{


    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    $newLastUsername = trim(preg_replace('/@.*/', '',$lastUsername));

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $newLastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}
```

security.yml

```
 providers:
        dsg_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: '%env(BASE_DSN)%'
            search_dn: '%env(SEARCH_DN)%'
            search_password: '%env(SEARCH_PWD)%'
            uid_key: '%env(UID_KEY)%'
            #filter: '({uid_key}={_username})'
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~

        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            provider: dsg_ldap
            dn_string: '%env(DN_STRING)%\{username}'
```

My LdapUserProvider.php

```
    class LdapUserProvider extends SymfonyLdapUserProvider
{
    /** @var array maps ldap groups to roles */
    private $groupMapping = [
        '**' => '**',
        '**' => '**',
        '**' => '**',
        '**' => '**'

    ];

    /** @var string extracts group name from dn string */
      private $groupNameRegExp = '/CN=(.+?),/';

    protected function loadUser($username, Entry $entry)
    {
        $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
        // Check if the entry has attribute with the group
        if (!$entry->hasAttribute('memberOf')) {
            return new User($username, '', $roles);
        }

        // Iterate through each group entry line
        foreach ($entry->getAttribute('memberOf') as $groupLine) {
            // Extract the group name from the line
            $groupName = $this->getGroupName($groupLine);
            // Check if the group is in the mapping
            if (array_key_exists($groupName, $this->groupMapping)) {
                // Map the group to the role(s) the user will have
                $roles[] = $this->groupMapping[$groupName];
            }
        }


        // Create and return the user object
        return new User($username, null, $roles);
    }

    /**
     * Get the group name from the DN
     * @param string $dn
     * @return string
     */
    private function getGroupName($dn)
    {
        $matches = [];
        return preg_match($this->groupNameRegExp, $dn, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
    }
}
```

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider.php

```
 public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{

    try {
        $this->ldap->bind($this->searchDn, $this->searchPassword);
        // what i added
        $username = trim(preg_replace('/@.*/', '',$username));
        $username = $this->ldap->escape($username, '', LdapInterface::ESCAPE_FILTER);
        $query = str_replace('{username}', $username, $this->defaultSearch);
        $search = $this->ldap->query($this->baseDn, $query);
    } catch (ConnectionException $e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username), 0, $e);
    }

    $entries = $search->execute();
    $count = \count($entries);

    if (!$count) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username));
    }

    if ($count > 1) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException('More than one user found');
    }

    $entry = $entries[0];

    try {
        if (null !== $this->uidKey) {
            $username = $this->getAttributeValue($entry, $this->uidKey);
        }
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    }

    return $this->loadUser($username, $entry);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `loadUserByUsername` function, add another query if the first one fails. Your `$this->defaultSearch` is probably a constant which represents an LDAP filter.

If you create the same line in the first `if (!$count) {...}` like this:

```
$query = str_replace('{username}', $username, "(userPrincipalName={username})");
```

and then execute that query, you are performing a second search for the userPrincipalName which is of the form *user@domain*

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it to work adding your suggestions. In addition I had to change dn_string: '%env(DN_STRING)%\{username}' to dn_string: ' '.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. If the answer is correct you can mark it as such ;-)